# MATCH lookup_array error after converting data to table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve: A value from intersection of row and column using `INDEX`+ `MATCH`.

Problem: The conversion of data to table resulted an **error** for **INDEX(column_num)** specifically **MATCH(lookup_array)**.

Calculation steps:`MATCH(J20,C3:F3,0)` > `MATCH(2011,C3:F3,0)` > `#N/A`

Whether the years list are headers or not, it's still the same. Everything else worked fine but only this part came out as error. Why?

-EDIT-

New problem: Year list as headers gave **error** for **MATCH(lookup_array)**.

[image]

Calculation steps: `MATCH(2011,$B$2:$F$2,0)` > `#N/A`

Comment: See those little green triangles in the upper left hand corner of `C3:E3`? That might be your problem.

Comment: `2011` may not be found because J20 and C3 aren't of the same data type. Perhaps one of them is a string, the other a number. Also beware of leading and trailing blanks.

Comment: It was converted into numbers, the problem was solved. But then, I tried to start over and convert the year list into headers, but it comes out with the same error again. This time there are no green triangles for C3:E3. Though C3:E3 has become `Book[#Headers]`